# cookie in MVC takes 2 page loads to register

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am creating an MVC application in which I have a button that shows hidden values and hides values.  The problem is, I need to press the button twice before the cookie change registers on the page.  Any help would be great, especially if you tell me exactly how to correct this.

So what is happening here is I have to press Show Not Active twice in order to get it to change to Hide Not Active, and vice versa.

```
if (Request.Cookies["showHidden"] != null)
{
    ViewBag.Show = Request.Cookies["showHidden"].Value;
}
else
{
    ViewBag.Show = "false"
}
@if (User.IsInRole("Data Manager"))
{
    if (ViewBag.Show != "true")
    {
        <text>
            @Html.ActionLink("Show Not Active", "Details", new
              { show = "true" }, new { @class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"                })
       </text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>   
            @Html.ActionLink("Hide Not Active", "Details", new 
              { show = "false" }, new { @class="btn btn-primary btn-                  sm })
       </text>
    }
```

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string show)
{
    if (show == "true")
    {
        if (this.Response.Cookies["showHidden"] == null
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("showHidden", "true");
            cookie.Expires = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
            this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        else
        {            
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("showHidden", "true");
            cookie.Expires = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
            this.Response.SetCookie(cookie);        
        }
    }
    if (show == "false")
    {        
        if (this.Response.Cookies["showHidden"] == null
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("showHidden", "false");
            cookie.Expires = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
            this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        else
        {            
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("showHidden", "false");
            cookie.Expires = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
            this.Response.SetCookie(cookie);        
        }

    }
    thing thing = db.thing.Find(id);
    if (thing == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(thing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I figured out how to get the button to change on every click and the hide/show to change on every click, but I now have another problem, the cookies are not persisting every time I leave the page, so I will post that in another thread.